# Why cannot access my scope.variable in partial view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with Angularjs and i want to understand something. I have a html page: 
...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
                $scope.myvalue = "TEST";

            } );
</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="MyController" >


    {{myvalue}}

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here i am able to display my value i defined in scope. I don't need to use Route since all are in the same page.

But when i divide my view with ng-view i am missing something. I don't understand why it's not working. Here is my code.

The plunker link is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xi0VEBvnHvDdIW5Mjkzs?p=preview)
When i try to add a partial i am getting a error about ngRoute. I provide library ngRoute and i use RouteProvider. What's missing please ?
Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hbf4F13cVoIuL7MtNg3B?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: On the singe page plunker, you are missing quotes.  $scope.myValue = 'TEST IT';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a JavaScript syntax error in the single page one.  You are missing quotes.  Change to the following.

```
$scope.myValue = 'TEST IT';
```

For the other one which is broken out, it looks like you're missing the import for Angular route and have a misnamed JavaScript variable due to capitalization in script.js.

Change `$scope.myvalue = "TEST"; to $scope.myValue = "TEST";`

and add the following to index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you've defined `myvalue` and in the partial you are calling `myValue`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

here you are: 
[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/aSwxoR9ZcdXH2XFav1Zo)

you forgot include route, its own module u need include its, and you have a little typo in partial. `{{myValue}}`

Answer (score 0):

just replace $scope.myValue = TEST IT with $scope.myValue = 'TEST IT'.

You have to define string type variable.

cheers!